# Android: Retrieve and decode JPEG

Tags: java, android

In the app I am developing, I want to download an image (jpeg) from an URL and show it. The code I have works so far, but I don't understand how is possible that for the same image, some time it takes 3 secs to decode and another it takes up to 200 secs. This is my code:

```
String attachmentUrl = attachment.getContentSrc();
long mills = System.currentTimeMillis();
//Get the stream from the URL
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(attachmentUrl).openConnection().getInputStream());
is.mark(attachment.getFileSize());
Log.d("AttachmentsUtils","Downloading Time: "+((System.currentTimeMillis()-mills)/1000)+" secs");
mills = System.currentTimeMillis();
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//Now, we only want the size of the image
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
//Calculate the sampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, THUMBNAIL_WIDTH, THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT);
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
//Reset the stream in order to decode it again, but this time, we will get the bitmap
is.reset();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
Log.d("AttachmentsUtils","Decode Time: "+((System.currentTimeMillis()-mills)/1000)+" secs. With sample "+options.inSampleSize);

//Return an scaled version of the bitmap
if(bm!=null){
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, THUMBNAIL_WIDTH, THUMBNAIL_HEIGHT, false);
}
```

I am trying with several images, but the largest has 1,332,828 bytes (1.3MB) and 1536×2048 px. As I said before, sometimes it decodes in 3 or 5 seconds, other it takes ages to decode it. I am using always the same `option.inSampleSize`.

I used this same code in another project before, using larger images, and it worked fine. The only different was that I was retrieving the inputStream from a file instead of from a URL, but I don't think this makes any difference, apart from the download time, obviously.

I've checked and the first decode for get the dimensions of the file takes like 2 or 3 secs, so that's not the problem. I am testing on a Nexus 4, so it has nothing to do with the device performance. I just don't have any idea why most times it takes so long, and a few times it works fine.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing your downloads over mobile networks or wifi. If your using 3G it wouldn't surprise me at all to see a lot of variance in the time it takes the file to download and process.

Comment: It is wifi, but I am talking about processing time, once the download is finished.